# Extend Asp Net Core Identity Relation

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

In Asp net core (3.1) Identity i want add a many to many relationship between user and TourOperators.
(The concept is that many user can follow many tour operators).

I have the tour operators class:

```
public class TourOperator
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Follow> Follows { get; set; }
}
```

I have extended the UserIdentity class:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Follow> Follow { get; set; }
}
```

I have the Follow class:

```
public class Follow
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    
    public int TourOperatorId { get; set; }
    public TourOperator TourOperator{ get; set; }
}
```

After execute the migration, why in the Follow table i have 4 field instead of 3?
I have the following field:
[image]

I think that ApplicationUserId couldn't be present

Comment: You need to tell EF that `UserId` is the key to link to `ApplicationUser`

Comment: In one word: **conventions**. `ApplicationUser` -> `ApplicationUserId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework has no way to link the `UserId` and `ApplicationUser` properties. So you either need to follow convention, whereby EF can make an educated guess. The simplest option is to rename your `string` property:

```
public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

Alternatively, you can configure it, for example using an attribute:

```
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser"]
public string UserId { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Or in the `OnModelCreating` method, for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Follow>()
    .WithOne(f => f.ApplicationUser)
    .HasForeignKey("UserId");
```